# Banner Image not showing and text alignment failure

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve below using Tailwind CSS Grid:

[image]

My HTML code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tw_style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>This is a Testing Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container h-screen mx-auto bg-red-100 grid grid-rows-10 gap-4">
    <!-- Banner Image (left) and Menu Button (right) in same Grid Row-->
        <section class="row-span-1">
            <banner class="" style="background-image: url(Banner.jpg)">
                <h1 class="pt-2 text-center align-top text-3xl font-black text-red-700">This is a Testing Site</h1>
            </banner>
            <button>
                
            </button>
        </section>

    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**[Q1]: Why the background image does not show up until I put a block or flex class `<banner class="block" style="background-image: url(Banner.jpg)">` ?**

**[Q2]: Why text in `<h1>` tag is not on the top of background image even though `align-top` is in place ?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: there is no html element named `banner`. When you use a `div` it works.

Q2: it is, however since the banner does not have a height defined it can't be on top

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tw_style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>This is a Testing Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container h-screen mx-auto bg-red-100 grid grid-rows-10 gap-4">
    <!-- Banner Image (left) and Menu Button (right) in same Grid Row-->
    <section class="row-span-1 grid grid-cols-10">
      <div class="bg-no-repeat bg-cover col-span-9" style="background-image: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/26BRQTezZrKak4BeE/giphy.gif')">
        <h1 class="pt-2 text-center align-top text-3xl font-black text-red-700">This is a Testing Site</h1>
      </div>
      <button class="col-span-1">
        Menu
      </button>
    </section>
    <div class="row-span-8 text-center text-6xl">Main content</div>
    <div class="row-span-1 bg-yellow text-center">Footer</div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Example pen: https://codepen.io/onewaveadrian/pen/MWpvwvx